# Is it possible to use objectify Ids on the client side?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm working on an android app with a GAE endpoint backend. I want to on the android side access the Id from an objectify entity, but it doesn't seem to exist on the client side. Is there a reason for this, or a way round it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you completely, but I'll make some comments.  First, objectify ID are just datastore ID's, which can be represented as a String or a long (actually just 56bits of a long).

So it is no problem to communicate these ID's between your Android app and your server.  If you want to use them as ID's on Android, i.e. for storing records in sqlite, that would be fine for the long id's.  The String ID's could be hashed into a long ID suitable for use as an ID on Android, but you would have to evaluate the potential for a hash collision.

Comment: The problem I have is that it seems that when using the generated client library the ID field is not included.

Comment: Yes. Do you know if there is a way to force it to include Id on the client side?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You could add an extra field to the entity (for the id) with @Ignore so ofy doesn't store it.